# Use PHP to duplicate div and randomize

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm using ACF with WordPress to loop through a set of images to display them:

```
<div class="logos">
  <?php if (have_rows('logos')) : while (have_rows('logos')): the_row();
      $image  = get_sub_field('logo');
      $link   = get_sub_field('logo_link');
      ?>
      <div class="img"><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>"></a></div>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
```

What I'm wondering is if it's possible to duplicate the div of `logos` 4 more times and then randomize the return of the loop of the images? Not sure if that's possible with PHP **or** if jQuery might be the better way to go about it instead?

Comment: if you want to loop execute 4 time then use for loop

Answer (score 2):

Yes that is possible! Instead of using `have_rows` you can use `get_field`. The result is an array. You can then use php's [rand](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) function and `foreach` to loop over the array.

Check this `ACF example` [enter link description here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/code-examples/) for batter understanding.

I didn't check the exact output of `get_field` in the example below, but you'll get the idea :)

```html
<?php

$images = get_field( 'logos' );
$images1 = rand( $images );
$images2 = rand( $images );
$images3 = rand( $images );
$images4 = rand( $images );

?>

<div class="logos">
    <?php foreach ( $images1 as $image ) : ?>
        <div class="img"><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $image['logo_link']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image['logo']['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['logo']['alt']; ?>"></a></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

<div class="logos">
    <?php foreach ( $images2 as $image ) : ?>
        <div class="img"><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $image['logo_link']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image['logo']['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['logo']['alt']; ?>"></a></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

<div class="logos">
    <?php foreach ( $images3 as $image ) : ?>
        <div class="img"><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $image['logo_link']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image['logo']['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['logo']['alt']; ?>"></a></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

<div class="logos">
    <?php foreach ( $images4 as $image ) : ?>
        <div class="img"><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $image['logo_link']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image['logo']['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['logo']['alt']; ?>"></a></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Or use a for loop:

```html
<?php $images = get_field( 'logos' ); ?>

<?php for ( $i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++ ) : $randImages = rand( $images ); ?>
    <div class="logos">
        <?php foreach ( $randImages as $image ) : ?>
            <div class="img"><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $image['logo_link']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image['logo']['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['logo']['alt']; ?>"></a></div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: Good idea buddy

Comment: @Sjors - is it `random($images);` or `rand($images);` ?

Comment: Oops, it's `rand()` actually, adjusted my answer